# ASP.NET , SqlDataReader and SqlCommand (There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I'm getting this error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

I don't know where is the problem. It's closed but still says it's open. Please help!

The first command is to get all employees that have vacation between two dates.

The second command I am using it to retrieve dates by ID.

Here is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
     con.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT distinct E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Vacation V ON E.EmployeeId = V.EmployeeId " +
                                     " WHERE ((V.Dates >= @Start AND V.Dates <= @End) ) ", con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", (Calendar1.SelectedDates[0]).Date.ToShortDateString());
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", (Calendar1.SelectedDates[Calendar1.SelectedDates.Count - 1]).Date.ToShortDateString());

    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
             Response.Write((dr[1]).ToString() + "  "); // Check if retrieves employee name
             // Now by Id I want to get all dates belong to specific employee
             SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT V.Dates FROM Vacation V " +
                                              " WHERE ((V.Dates >= @Start AND V.Dates <= @End) ) ", con);
             cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", (Calendar1.SelectedDates[0]).Date.ToShortDateString());
             cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", (Calendar1.SelectedDates[Calendar1.SelectedDates.Count - 1]).Date.ToShortDateString());
             cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]));                                    

             using (SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 while (dr2.Read())
                 {
                      Response.Write(Convert.ToDateTime(dr2[0]));
                 }
             }

             Response.Write("<br/>");
         } 

         GridView7.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         GridView7.DataBind();
    }
    con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your connection string:

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Comment: Thank you for your respons but do you mean in my webconfig? it says it not allowd.

Comment: Yes, add it to the connection string. For example, <add connectionString="data source=yourserver;Initial Catalog=your DB;Trusted_Connection=True" name="ApplicationServices" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

Comment: I found the problem. The gridView was Inside the first sqlconnection. When I moved it out side then every Think working as it should. Thank you again.

Comment: Great! Good luck with your project.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this question? Thank you in advance:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018174/asp-net-multiple-sqlcommands-in-one-gridview