# asp.net multiple sqlcommands in one GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqlcommand

I have problem to show multiple sql command in one GridView. Maybe I don't need two sqlcommands to show from two tables but I don't know how to do.
The first command is to get all employees that have vacation between two dates.
The second command I am using it to retrieve dates by ID. But I don't know how to Bind them both to one GridView to show as attached image. Thank you in advance.

What I get Now is
Albert  2016-03-16 
Albert  2016-03-17
Albert  2016-03-18
Johanna 2016-03-17
Johanna 2016-03-18
Eric 2016-03-18

Instead of
Albert  2016-03-16, 2016-03-17, 2016-03-18
Johanna 2016-03-17, 2016-03-18
Eric    2016-03-18
I think I have to loop between two While statment and maybe with one sqlcommand? 
[image]

My code is:

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT distinct E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName  
 FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Vacation V ON E.EmployeeId = V.EmployeeId " +
  " WHERE ((V.Dates >= @Start AND V.Dates <= @End) ) ", con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", (Calendar1.SelectedDates[0]).Date.ToShortDateString());
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", (Calendar1.SelectedDates[Calendar1.SelectedDates.Count - 1]).Date.ToShortDateString());
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
 {
   while (dr.Read())
    {

 Response.Write((dr[1]).ToString() + "  "); // Cheack if retrivs Employeename
 // Now By Id I want to get all dates belong to specifik employee

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(" SELECT V.Dates FROM Vacation V " +
" WHERE ((V.Dates >= @Start AND V.Dates <= @End) ) ", con);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", (Calendar1.SelectedDates[0]).Date.ToShortDateString());
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", (Calendar1.SelectedDates[Calendar1.SelectedDates.Count - 1]).Date.ToShortDateString());
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]));                                    
using (SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
{
 while (dr2.Read())
    {
    //Response.Write(Convert.ToDateTime(dr2[0]));
     GridView7.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
GridView7.DataBind();
    }

   }
       Response.Write("<br/>");
 } 


  }
    con.close();
}
GridView7.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView7.DataBind();
```

Comment: Do you need to handle the information as a column? why not using all the dates they took vacations in a single nvarchar(max) column and just adding a comma between them? i'm saying this because the way you are trying to achieve this, is gonna be a mess, since all dates doesn't match between employees, you can use a dynamic SQL pivot table but that will leave you with a bunch of null (or blank) spaces.

Comment: @thepanch Thank you for your response But I need to show the result in a table or GridView. Is that possible? It's Ok with  dynamic SQL pivot table even that will leave  with a bunch of null (or blank) spaces. Is that possible then? Thank you again.

Comment: @thepanch : My code is working if I use Response.Write(.....) for example:
With Response.Write((dr[1]).ToString() + "  "); 
And
Response.Write(Convert.ToDateTime(dr2[0]));

I can retriv as I want but I don't want it to Write on the page as it is.
I want to show them in a table , GridView or dynamic SQL pivot table

Answer (score 0):

The FOR XML PATH syntax allows your query to group several values in a single one:

```
SELECT 
    E.EmployeeId, 
    E.FirstName,
    REPLACE(STUFF((
        SELECT 
            COALESCE('¶' + V.Dates, '')
        FROM 
            Vacation V 
        WHERE 
            V.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId AND V.Dates >= @Start AND V.Dates <= @End
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '¶', ', ') AS VacationDates
FROM 
    Employee E
```

You can replace the `', '` separator by something else if you want.

Note: Sorry for the multipe edits. I am just not sure how you connect the employees, vacations and dates. This piece of code basically shows the idea for the FOR XML PATH syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your respons , I got error "Must declare the scalar variable "@Start""   but I'am declaring as  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", (Calendar1.SelectedDates[0]).Date.ToShortDateString());

Comment: You get that error when inserting this query in your code, or when testing it directly in the database?

Comment: It's Ok, but My code is working if I use Response.Write(.....) for example:
With Response.Write((dr[1]).ToString() + "  "); 
And
Response.Write(Convert.ToDateTime(dr2[0]));

I can retriv as I want but I don't want it to Write on the page as it is.
I want to show them in a table , GridView or dynamic SQL pivot table

Comment: When I inserting in my code but he answered me that he tought I runned XML path or somethin like that so it will not work his code. Actualy my code as it is , it's working but as I said Before I want  I want to show them in a table , GridView or dynamic SQL pivot table. But I Think I must use the same name of sqlcommand. I use two sqlcommand becouse I have to retrieve first the employeeId. If you study my code.. then how can I use one command instead of two sqlcommand and two ExecuteReader()? I Think the problem is that I use two command and ExecuteReader(). Thank you for your time

Comment: My answer is a way to do it with only one query. I don't know what error message you get exactly. I usually save my query as a stored procedure and call the procedure from code. You can test my query in the database first (providing some values for Start and End) and see if the output is what you want. If it is, then we can see how to make it work in your code.

Comment: Sorry I thought you was the other guy "thepanch". I was confused. Sorry. I tried your letest code and direct in SQL Managment Studio returns all NULL vacationDates but there is dates in database. And when I tried inserting in my code it says "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: The field VacationDates will be output as a character string. So you cannot convert it to date. It should look like this for a given employee: "2016-03-18, 2016-03-17, 2016-03-16". As for why that data column is empty... I can see that it will be empty for some employees (that can be corrected easily) but I thought there would be data for others. I assume that you gave appropriate values to "@Start" and "@End" when you tried it... Oh, I just removed a redundant WHERE in the query; did you see that in your test?

Comment: Yes I deleted a redundant WHERE from the beginig.  Insttead of Start  I wrote 2016-0315 and End 2016-03-20 and stil give me NULL for all employees (about 10 employees) even for those who are working, when I tried direct in Managment sql server. It's perfekt to show me even for those who are working. I want to see all employees but dates beside them for those who are in vacation between start and end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106434/discussion-between-jonas-willander-and-connorsfan).